# How to express a series expansion into a power law form?

Tags: logarithms, power-series

Suppose I have a series like

$P\sim A+\epsilon B\,lnM+O(\epsilon ^{2})$

and I want to express it into a power law form. The answer is

$P\sim AM^{\epsilon B/A}+O(\epsilon ^{2})$.

Another example. The expression

$Nl\left \{ 1+\frac{\epsilon }{8}\left [ -1+ln\left ( \frac{2\pi N}{L} \right ) \right ] \right \}$

can be written into the following power law form:

$Nl\left ( 1-\frac{\epsilon }{8} \right )\left ( \frac{2\pi N}{L} \right )^{\frac{\epsilon }{8}}$

The problem is I am not getting how to go from step 1 to step 2.

Can somebody provide me with an explanation?

Comment: What *means* here "series" and "convert"?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla The series here is an expansion in small parameter $/epsilon$. By "converting" I mean to do some manipulation which transforms it into a power law form.

Comment: Again, what *means* "manipulation"? The first $P$ and the 2nd $P$  are **different**.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I meant that by some algebraic manipulation the first P can be written in the form expressed by the second P. Does my question sound vague to you or is it not making any sense?

Comment: You can "convert" any $X$ in any $Y$ by the "algebraic manipulation" $X\rightarrow X + (Y − X)$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla that I understand but how write the aforementioned expressions into the power law form in the 2nd step.